# How was the 1849 "Proclamation to the People of California" announcing the formation of a Constitution communicated to the people?

Tags: 19th-century, government, california, communication

The images below appear to be an official copy of the 1849 **Proclamation to the People of California** announcing the formation of a Constitution. It is signed by Secretary of State [Captain H.W. Halleck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_Halleck) (his signature can be compared with his signature on this [letter](https://ia802901.us.archive.org/BookReader/BookReaderImages.php?zip=/8/items/documentos119910172vall/documentos119910172vall_jp2.zip&file=documentos119910172vall_jp2/documentos119910172vall_0502.jp2&scale=8&rotate=0) that he wrote to [William Hartnell](https://hartnellpapers.blogspot.com)).
How would this proclamation have been communicated to all the people in California?
(There is a Spanish version also [here - page 1](https://ia902901.us.archive.org/BookReader/BookReaderImages.php?zip=/8/items/documentos119910172vall/documentos119910172vall_jp2.zip&file=documentos119910172vall_jp2/documentos119910172vall_0449.jp2&scale=8&rotate=0) and [here - page 2](https://ia902901.us.archive.org/BookReader/BookReaderImages.php?zip=/8/items/documentos119910172vall/documentos119910172vall_jp2.zip&file=documentos119910172vall_jp2/documentos119910172vall_0450.jp2&scale=8&rotate=0)).

[image: Proclamation Page 1]

[image: Proclamation Page 2]

The above documents form part of the [Vallejo Family Papers Collection](https://archive.org/search.php?query=documentos%20para%20la%20historia%20de%20california&and%5B%5D=creator%3A%22vallejo%2C%20mariano%20guadalupe%2C%201808-1890%22)  reference BANC MSS C-B 441 at The Bancroft Library, University of California, Berkeley.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Territory Governor Riley, who had summoned the constitutional convention, had 1,000 English and 250 Spanish copied printed "*post-haste*" and distributed around the state. In addition, many of the convention delegates themselves stood for the election just 4 weeks later, by their campaigning further promulgating news and description of the pending constitution.

Within a few days (it is claimed) of the signing, "*the constitution was carried to every mining camp and rancho in the land.*"

To  wit, Bancroft's massive [History of California, Vol. VI. 1848-1859, (pp 305)](https://archive.org/details/historycaliforn05bancgoog/page/n318/mode/2up?q=Constitution) notes:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 12):

It was published at least twice in [the newspaper *Alta California*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Daily_Alta_California), on [November 1](https://cdnc.ucr.edu/?a=d&d=WAC18491101.2.22.3) and [November 8](https://cdnc.ucr.edu/?a=d&d=WAC18491108.2.2). It may have appeared in other newspapers as well, but this was what I was able to find with a quick search.

[image]